# I ran timeshift to fix an error, Now I can run `systemctl` and `systemd` without `sudo` - My attempts to undo this have been unsuccessful

Tags: command-line, sudo, systemd

I have a Dell Inspiron 3501 running Ubuntu 20.04.  I recently had an issue with bluetooth and I ran Timeshift restore to fix it.  Eventually I was able to fix the bluetooth.  However, I found out afterward that I no longer require `sudo` to run `systemctl/systemd` commands.  I have checked the `/etc/sudoers` files and I can't see anything unusual in them that would allow such.  I have always been required to use the `sudo` command with both of these commands until now.  Any suggestions would be appreciated thank you.

Ok so I found permissions got changed on /etc/passwd

ran `$sudo chmod 600 /etc/passwd`
so that's fixed.  I'm still unsure how to undo the systemctl/systemd issue.  Anyway I have totally removed Timeshift, I kept the logs.  I have no idea if anything else got altered, that's all I have noticed thus far.

Update- I just discovered that the name on my laptop has been removed/replaced as well:
`I have no name!@mylaptop:~$`- I definitely didn't do this either.  I am really unhappy with Timeshift.  I see that my laptop has a builtin backup.  I don't want to backup anything at the moment with this in the condition that is.

Comment: Can you give us an example of the commands that used to need sudo that now do not?  Have you rebooted your system? Did you elevate to `sudo su` and forget to exit?

Comment: Yes I have rebooted the system several times and I am still able to run systemctl and systemd.  I have the root user disabled.  `$ su`
Password: <br/>
su: Authentication failure<br/>

Comment: I can now use `vi /etc/passwd` without `sudo`.  As far as my history goes only systemctl, systemd and vi were affected

Comment: I can run vi /etc/passwd but I have to run `sudo vi /var/log/rkhunter.log`.  Not sure what to make of that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I decided to revert my laptop to pre-shipped factory default settings. Dell provides this built-in recovery option.  I no longer have permission to access either of the built-in recovery options. I was able to recover my wife's laptop so I'm pretty sure I had access to this recovery feature prior to the Timeshift restore. {{As an aside this is what happened to my wife's laptop.  She installed a program called Davinci Resolve.  I ran the uninstall and noticed there were a ton of "davinci" files remaining.  Little did I know that Davinci is part of the kernel. So I went ahead and cleaned up a bunch of Davinci files which were in the kernel.  I then tried unsuccessfully to revert the mistake and ended up restoring the laptop. Just a word to the wise, BE CAREFUL!}}  I am currently downloading the iso from canonical in order to reinstall Ubuntu 20.04 OS. I recommend staying away from Timeshift if you have a pre-built Linux machine. If you did a self installation, use at your own risk.  Based on this experience I personally don't recommend it.  I used Timeshift with default settings, I excluded the /home and / directories.  I had it setup for weekly backups and saving 3.
Final Update-
Ultimately after a long drawn out process I finally created a bootable recovery drive from my wife's Dell.  I almost thought I lost the laptop but it came back alive and well. I will reiterate the process was nightmareish.  I'm not certain what got altered but it caused a lot of time and pain.  Once again if you have a pre-built device with builtin recovery, do the following:

First: ensure the USB drives/sticks are formatted as FAT 32.  Linux doesn't recognize NTFS.

Second: Use the provided tools (assuming the laptop is a Linux machine and not a Microsoft/Windows machine) to create the backups only after verifying step 1.  Either way FAT 32 works on BOTH devices.  NTFS only on Microsoft/Windows and it's also a solution if you need to save files greater than 4GB.

Third:If the computer gets stuck in a recovery loop, DON'T remove the thumbdrive until AFTER the reboot completes. I am so thankful I didn't brick this laptop. I came close.

I would also like to add that I am able to run `systemctl` without `sudo` on my reinstallation. I'm not sure why that is, but it apparently comes that way from Dell.